# Creating Master Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to create a Master SP that will contain two stored procedures that will be used for a SSRS report.

```
procBMI
procFRisk
```

What is the best approach in creating a master SP that will hold both of these SPs so that both SPs will be used in a SSRS dataset?

Comment: What do you mean by "*hold*"?  Do you mean that your master SP will *execute* the other two SPs?  If so, then that's easy.  If not, then I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I should have stated execute the other two SPs.

Comment: Here are the two SPs I would like to execute from the Master SP       SP1 = BMI_Provider_Patients_Seen                                                     SP2 = Fall_Risk_Patients_Seen

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
CREATE PROC MasterSP AS

    EXEC SP1;

    EXEC SP2;

GO
```

Comment: Thank you!  but it is telling me that the procedure expects parameter @start_date

Comment: then you'll need to supply that parameter. Are parameters common to both procedures? If so you could pass parameters to the main SP and then pass them to the SPs that you are calling. My concern is (and I don't wish to be rude) that you get an error with an obvious solution but you're asking for help on here. Maybe you need to invest sometime learning the basic of writing stored procedures in T-SQL or you will spend all your time posting questions on SO. Apologies if I'm wrong about this./